# Software that tells me which author's style my text most closely resembles

Tags: web-apps, text-processing

#### TL;DR:

I need a software that analyses a text I provide, compares it to its (hopefully large) database of authors, and finally tells me which author's style it most closely resembles. (It need not be limited to inferring such authorship, as it may be of interest to writers curious about how their style compares to others'.) The software should preferably be a web-app or other lightweight freeware.

#### Details:

When I first heard of [I Write Like](http://iwl.me), I hoped it would be a good Bayesian analysis of how similar text is to a wide database of authors. But it only considers 50 authors, despite being almost 7 years old. Are there any similar but better treatments? I could see an obvious application, namely literary agencies using such software to sift through their submissions for a style they seek.

Comment: do you have access to the databases you speak of? This question seems impossible without having access to the data to compare it you? Please correct me if I am wrong. Only reason I mention that is because this seems impossible without a data set like google has and they got sued [Google has scanned and made machine-readable more than 20 million books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Book_Search_Settlement_Agreement)

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife I don't have such access, though the maker of IWL or an alternative may. Training a Bayesian filter may not require copyright-violating long-term retention.

Comment: tell that to the authors! Lol ( I am kidding) Bottom line is I think the reason it ( the software you seek) does not exist, is because there is not large enough market for it (yet) (demand is not there) and you need a ton of data to do the analysis. Have you searched for datasets? If you have the data you can easily do this yourself without paying for software. ( I have no idea how time sensitive this is)