# Textual authorship testing options?

Tags: text-processing

There's a [pretty remarkable](https://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/03/software-helps-identify-anonymous-writers-or-helps-them-stay-that-way/) piece of software called [`jstylo`](https://github.com/psal/jstylo) from [Drexel University](https://psal.cs.drexel.edu/index.php/JStylo-Anonymouth), but it appears to have been [untouched](https://github.com/psal/jstylo/issues/12#issuecomment-226476041) for a couple of years.

Are there any comparable options to this that analyze authorship between texts in a highly reliable manner such as this?

Comment: Could you please at least add on what OS the software should run, and what are your pricing opinions (how much are you willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions)? Also, what formats are the texts in that the software must understand? Also see: [Software that tells me which author's style my text most closely resembles](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42926/185)